# Mocking IHttpClientFactory - xUnit C#

Tags: c#, httpclient, xunit, fixtures, httpclientfactory

I was trying to build a generic HTTP service in my project (c# with .net core 2.1), and I have done it as per the below snippet `HttpService`.

I also started using it by calling it from my business logic class which uses this generic `PostAsync` method to post an HTTP call to a 3rd party with a content in body. It works perfectly.

But, when I tried to test it, I failed!
Actually when I tried debugging (testing mode), I get `null` response when the debugger comes to this line `var result = await _httpService.PostAsync("https://test.com/api", content);` in business class `Processor` even with fake objects and mocks, although it works normally in debugging mode without testing/mocking.

**HTTP service:**

```
public interface IHttpService
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string requestUri, HttpContent content);
}

public class HttpService : IHttpService
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public HttpService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string requestUri, HttpContent content)
    {
        var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return response;
    }
}
```

**Business class:**

```
public class Processor : IProcessor
{
    private readonly IHttpService _httpService;

    public Processor() { }

    public Processor(IHttpService httpService, IAppSettings appSettings)
    {
        _httpService = httpService;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostToVendor(Order order)
    {
        // Building content
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order, Formatting.Indented);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        // HTTP POST
        var result = await _httpService.PostAsync("https://test.com/api", content); // returns null during the test without stepping into the method PostAsyn itself

        return result;
    }
}
```

**Test class:**

```
public class MyTests
{
    private readonly Mock<IHttpService> _fakeHttpMessageHandler;
    private readonly IProcessor _processor; // contains business logic
    private readonly Fixture _fixture = new Fixture();

    public FunctionTest()
    {
        _fakeHttpMessageHandler = new Mock<IHttpService>();
        _processor = new Processor(_fakeHttpMessageHandler.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Post_To_Vendor_Should_Return_Valid_Response()
    {
        var fakeHttpResponseMessage = new Mock<HttpResponseMessage>(MockBehavior.Loose, new object[] { HttpStatusCode.OK });

        var responseModel = new ResponseModel
        {
            success = true,
            uuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        };

        fakeHttpResponseMessage.Object.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseModel), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var fakeContent = _fixture.Build<DTO>().Create(); // DTO is the body which gonna be sent to the API
        var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fakeContent), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        _fakeHttpMessageHandler.Setup(x => x.PostAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), content))
            .Returns(Task.FromResult(fakeHttpResponseMessage.Object));

        var res = _processor.PostToVendor(fakeContent).Result;
        Assert.NotNull(res.Content);
        var actual = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseModel);
        var expected = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in mock set up:

```
_fakeHttpMessageHandler.Setup(x => x.PostAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), content))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(fakeHttpResponseMessage.Object));
```

Second parameter for PostAsync method expected to be `content`, but since StringContent is a reference type, `content` you setup in mock is different from `content` you creating in processor. If you change it to next one, it should work as you expect:

```
    _fakeHttpMessageHandler.Setup(x => x.PostAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<StringContent>()))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(fakeHttpResponseMessage.Object));
```

P.S. null response to PostAsync means that method has default setup, which means that it will return default value

Comment: It worked, but may you tell me why? I mean how this was the root cause of failure?

Comment: As i said, when you setup Mock, you tell framework what method should return when you provide specific values. When you say It.IsAny<*>(),  it means that it will return provided output for any input, but when you provide other object it expects exactly that object. If second parameter to Post method would have Value Type(int, double etc) it would work as you expect it, but StringContent is a reference type and that's why you have the problem

Comment: Then no need for `fakeContent` which I'm using there, correct?

Comment: It really depends on your test case, first of all you need to pass something here `PostToVendor(fakeContent)`

Comment: Thanks, it worked successfully! and for `fakeContent` it should be there as the method should have a content in the end :)